# Unable to redirect mail to outside domains

Tags: postfix

I am trying to redirect mail from local user accounts to other local user accounts as well as outside email accounts.

Right now i am using /etc/aliases, with alias_maps pointing to this file, i had double check at 'postconf -n'.

In my aliases file i have set:

```
# Put your local aliases here.
# <local username1>: <username2>@<domain>, <username3>@<domain>, ...
teste: teste2@X.pt, teste3@Y.pt
```

I am able to redirect from local account teste to teste2 but not able to forward to teste3 from an outside domain.

This is a smarthost from X domain only, that is using a remote mail server where i have both X and Y domains, i am not sending mails to outside of this remote mail server.

Any log that you may think useful just say it.
Thanks!

UPDATE1:

I have made with sendmail and it said at mail.log: 550-Verification failed for  550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)) This remote.X.pt is my smarthost, but this email account exists.

Here i have my main.cf if you need: pastebin.com/d9hZaTwp

UPDATE2:

I have discovered the source of this problem but still dont understand how some mails have pass through:

```
Dec  6 12:20:20 remote.gfe-tec.pt postfix/smtp[22491]: 8A02C257828: to=<teste3@Y.pt>, orig_to=<teste@X.pt>, relay=cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt[94.126.172.90]:25, delay=165, delays=0/0.01/165/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1cEEjM-003ltK-1M)
Dec  6 12:44:58 remote.gfe-tec.pt postfix/smtp[23985]: E4DC92581E0: to=<teste3@Y.pt>, orig_to=<teste@remote.X.pt>, relay=cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt[94.126.172.90]:25, delay=165, delays=0/0.01/165/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host cpanel.ideiasfrescas.pt[94.126.172.90] said: 550-Verification failed for <Xserver@remote.X.pt> 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Mostly it sends with the domain used in my remote mail server, but rarely send with the domain as i expected who his X.pt and not remote.X.pt.

UPDATE3:

After a while i discover that this problem was caused when i send mails from an outside domain, in this case gmail, that i have used to test, that adds a wrong sender (@remote.X.pt instead of @X.pt), and it crashs in my remote server.

With Outlook, Mail app and local roundcube this doesnt happen.

Do you know how can i solve this?

Comment: Are you able to send a mail to teste3@outsidedomain.com from the commandline? <code>mail teste3@outsidedomain.com</code> What does the mail.log file say?

Comment: thanks Jeff W.! i have made with sendmail and it said at mail.log: 550-Verification failed for <root@remote.X.pt> 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)) This remote.X.pt is my smarthost, but this email account exists

Comment: i have also send to a gmail account and same result. =/ dont know really what can be´

Comment: Remote.x.pt is a different server that the one you are sending the mail from?

Comment: I am sending mails from my remote.x.pt to my remote (ISP) mail server mail.x.pt, there i have this account that i am trying to send mails. Here i have my main.cf if you need: http://pastebin.com/d9hZaTwp

Comment: This might help you. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have already config postfix as a smarthost, is working perfectly, i am only unable to send mails to other domains.

Comment: It seems to me that your mail server is looking at the SENDER address and trying to verify its a real address in its mail DB and that its allowed to send mail. are you certain that the sender address "root@remote.X.pt" exists as an authorized mail user on your mail server? I would expect your mail server to have addresses like "user@X.pt" or "webmaster@X.pt"

Comment: also, the mail.log you provided, is that from your mail server or the remote server?

Comment: Thanks again for the responses Jeff W.! I didnt mess with root user to receive or send mails. How can i authorize this user as a mail user? I dont have it at my Open Directory? yes it have adresses with @X.pt. This mail.log is from my mail server, i cannot access those logs i think at my remote server. There i only have access to a cpanel =/

Comment: I have found the source of this problem, and it seems that the client that i am using is creating this, but i will do more tests

Comment: This problem is caused by my roundcube client =X